# Embedded Tomcat in OSGi Felix Container

Tags: tomcat, osgi, apache-felix

I have used an embedded tomcat 7.0.53 in Eclipse to run the gateway at localhost. It works well when I run the gateway in Eclipse. 
Now I want to run the gateway in a OSGi Felix container, but I got a tomcat error:

```
LifeCycleException. Here is the the detailed error report:

2014-08-18 17:57:48 [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] SEVERE - A child container failed during start
2014-08-18 17:57:48 [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] SEVERE - A child container failed during start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)    
at at.ac.tuwien.auto.iotsys.gateway.obix.server.TomcatServerNoSecurity.<init>(TomcatServerNoSecurity.java:73)   
at at.ac.tuwien.auto.iotsys.gateway.IoTSySGateway$2.run(IoTSySGateway.java:301)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)   
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start    
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)    
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 8 more
```

Since the error report is too vague, I have no idea where the error comes from.

Does anyone ever embedded a tomcat in an OSGi Felix Container? Or does anyone have an idea about this problem?
Thx!

Comment: Unfortunately can't help much with the problem, but maybe try with Pax Web (https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web), it tries to take the pain away from such cases. And Tomcat is also supported.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have to keep using OSGi Felix, that is required.

Comment: Pax Web doesn't replace OSGi Felix, it sits on top, as your Tomcat, but gives you easier configuration, etc.. or OSGi-HttpService configurable in an OSGi way.

Comment: great, I will have a look on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the http port is blocked. May you still had tomcat running from eclipse?

Comment: Thanks for yours answer. Yes it works without any problem from eclipse. Should I modify the code of tomcat server, or should I modify the osgi bundle build files? I just have no idea where is the problem